# How to find the exact numbers of positive and negative roots of the polynomial by using Descartes rule

Tags: polynomials

How to find the exact numbers of positive and negative roots of the polynomial $x^4-12x^2+4$ by using Descartes rule of sign. I can find the maximum number of positive and negative roots using the rule. But how to find the exact numbers?

Comment: In this case, Descartes rule is not sufficient. But substituting $\ x^2=t\ $ allows to find all the roots of this polynomial.